# VMWare additional drives

Tags: vmware-converter, image

I have a system that I imaged using VMWare Converter, and it runs perfectly.  However, I have a second drive on the system that I did not originally image.

How can I image the second drive and add it to the virtual machine?

Answer (score 6):

Just run VMWare Converter again and only image the second drive, you can then just move the `.vmdk` to the same folder as the original VM, delete VM #2 and add the disk to the machine. The virtual equivalent of pulling a physical drive out of one computer, and plugging it into another.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just create a second virtual drive and then copy the files from the original drive onto it? (Either from the imaged VM itself after adding the new virtual drive, or by mounting both the new virtual drive and the existing drive in the same system..)

Comment: LOL, yes, suppose I could.  i did think of that, but thought it would be easier if there was a way ti image it into VMware.  The drive has about 160gb on it.

Thanks,
Tony